# Hide/disable VueJs Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex, vue-router

I have a bunch of components, and the users are allowed to access only certain components based on their permissions. How to disable the component?

These are the routes:

```
  {
    path: "/administration",
    name: "Administration",
    component: PageAdministration,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      neededPermissions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/settings/overview",
    name: "SettingsOverview",
    component: PageSettingsOverview,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true,
      showComponent: true,
     },
  },
  { path: "/:notFound(.*)", name: "NotFound", component: NotFound },
```

I have an **authorizeUser** function to authorize users, and I'd like to change the **showComponent** from routes based on the user's permissions. But I am not sure where to change the **showComponent** inside the function to disable the component.

```
if (currentUser!== 0 and to?.meta?.neededPermissions!== 0), {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentUser.teams.length; i++) {
      const team = currentUser.teams[i];
      console.log(to.meta.neededPermissions);
      const validPermissions = team.permissions.filter((item) => {
        return to.meta.neededPermissions.includes(item.permissionType);
      });                                                                              
      const mappedValidPermissions = validPermissions.map((item) => {
        return item.permissionType;
      });                                                                               
      if (
        !to.meta.neededPermissions.every((i) =>
          mappedValidPermissions.includes(i)
        ) 
      ) {
        isAllowed = false;
        to.meta.showComponent= false
        next({ path: "/:notFound(.*)" });
        break;
      }
      else to.meta.showComponent= true
    }
    if (isAllowed) {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();    
  }
```

Here is the router-link referring the router

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4" v-if="$route.meta.showComponent">
        <router-link class="card" to="/administration">
          <div class="card-img-top">
            <i class="hi hi-people" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Teams & Users</h5>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using navigation guards

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  if (
    // make sure the user is authenticated
    !isAuthenticated &&
    // Avoid an infinite redirect
    to.name !== 'Login'
  ) {
   // redirect the user to the login page
    return { name: 'Login' }
  }
})
```

[Documentation with more complex examples](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)